# Best way to display data (object) in the template ANGULAR5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

what is the best way to display data in template Angular5 for this case :

I load data from Firestore (=firebase) here:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.authService.afAuth.authState;
    this.user.subscribe((auth) => {
      if (auth) {
            this.itemService.getTestMembers(auth.uid).subscribe(testMembers => {
            this.testMembers = testMembers;
          });
      }
  });
```

}

Firestore response is : `[{"email":"john@gmail.com","name":"John"}]`

**1°** First solution in the template to display the name:

```
<span>{{testMembers[0]?.name}}</span>
```

Works, the name is displayed But I have an error : `TypeError: _co.testMembers is undefined`

---

**2°** Second solution in the code to display the name:

```
userName: string;
 ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.authService.afAuth.authState;
    this.user.subscribe((auth) => {
      if (auth) {
            this.itemService.getTestMembers(auth.uid).subscribe(testMembers => {
            this.testMembers = testMembers;
            **this.userName = (JSON.stringify(testMembers[0].name)); <-- here**
          });
      }
  });
```

What is the best solution, or perhaps there is another solution. Thank you
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a delay in the service response as it is asynchronous so you should be adding a `if` condition before you access the object as below

```
this.user.subscribe((auth) => {
      if (auth) {
            this.itemService.getTestMembers(auth.uid).subscribe(testMembers => {
            this.testMembers = testMembers;
            if(testMembers.length > 0 ) {//////////add this
                    this.userName = (JSON.stringify(testMembers[0].name)); 
            }
          });
      }
  });
```

Comment: Ok cool, thank you for this point.

So you think it's better to create "name" in the code ?

Comment: yes. I also recommend to have `models` for strict typing

Answer (score 1):

You can also add condition on HTML like

```
<span> {{testMembers ? testMembers[0]?.name : ' '}} </span>
```

As getting data may take some time and HTML excute first so this condition is help to avoid this error.

Comment: ah yes cool thank you. Do you think it is more effective to add data directly in the template like that ?

Comment: Yes. It would more effective and reduce unwanted condition on component ts file.